# Solving SQS Lambda Over-polling when bursting

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-lambda, error-handling, amazon-sqs, throttling

I have a scenario where I would like to use SQS to trigger Lambda functions to index documents in Elasticsearch. The issue I have is that the number of messages enqueued will range from 0 to hundreds of thousands, depending on application activity.

To avoid overwhelming Elasticsearch I need to limit how many Lambda functions are running concurrently. While I can set a reserved concurrency, when large numbers of messages are enqueued and the number of SQS pollers scales up this will result in a lot of throttling.

Options I have considered:

1. **Catch throttled messages (DLQ) and requeue for processing**. This seems terribly inefficient and messages may be requeued many times.
2. **Set a random message timer to artificially throttle**. Again, quite inefficient as it would introduce an artificial wait time even if it is the only message in the queue. A variation is to only set the wait timer when requeuing throttled messages.
3. **FIFO queue with a single message group id**. When a large number of messages are enqueued the max throughput for FIFO queues may be exceeded.
4. **Abandon the 'push' method and schedule Lambdas to poll the queue using CloudWatch Events**. Would need to implement a longer poll time (e.g. 1 minute) so may take longer to process messages.
5. **Abandon the 'push' method and use the traditional worker instance**. It's tried and tested, and can control concurrency/timing, but feels like I should be able to avoid IaaS for this?!

I've read a bunch of articles but there doesn't appear to be any clean solution for this problem, surprisingly, as I'm sure this is an extremely common problem. If we could set the SQS poller concurrency to match the Lambda concurrency that would be nice :)

Thanks,
John

Comment: What is the core problem? Does a small Reserved Concurrency cause a problem if there are lots of messages enqueued? Or are you just worried about the backlog?

Comment: Hi John. The core problem is that the number of Lambda pollers will scale up as the queue size increases and overwhelm the small number of concurrent Lambdas processing the queue resulting in failed messages due to throttling. This seems like an oversight that should be addressed by Amazon...

Comment: Sounds like having SQS triggering Lambda is not an appropriate architecture. Perhaps trigger Lambda once per minute, or use an EC2 instance instead of Lambda?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking that the traditional consumer instances approach (number 5 above) might be a safer way to manage this. Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

AWS released a new feature allowing to set the MaxConcurrency which will limit the number of concurrent Lambdas triggered by SQS:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/01/aws-lambda-maximum-concurrency-amazon-sqs-event-source/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-maximum-concurrency-of-aws-lambda-functions-when-using-amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source/